# I want to find ways to get past phone interviews

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, job-search

English is my second language. I have strong technical skills, good English reading and writing, but my spoken English could use some improvement. I rarely get a callback after a phone interview because of my spoken English communication. I am working to improve my spoken English, but in the meantime .

I want to find ways to get past phone interviews.

Comment: Hello Emilio, and welcome to [workplace.se]! To get you better answers, I am going to focus your question a little bit. If you think I left out something important, please feel free to [edit] the question to add details back in. Thanks for the great question!

Comment: please if you can improve the question...just do it. Thanks

Comment: I think this is closer to what you're asking Emilio -- I work in a country where I need to interview in another language as well. Good luck with your search!

Comment: yes,this is more focus, I think

Comment: [Related question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/15270/2322) - probably not a duplicate though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning to speak a foreign language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I improve at phone interviews in a second language?

If you are sure that your English language skills are the thing holding you back (rather than the lack of other skills), then there is no good way to "get past" the phone interviews without improving your English skills. And the way to improve at anything is to **practice**.

Do you have English-speaking friends?

Perhaps they would be willing to talk with you on the phone on occasion, provide feedback, and help you improve. Have them play the part of the interviewer, while you practice interviewing.

Record your practices, and play them back to see how you sound.

Listen to English-language radio/television/podcasts. Repeat what you are hearing.